# How to create a scalable Moebius-strip in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, math, topology

A [moebius strip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_strip) is a surface with one side.

How would one define such an object in XAML/WPF?
How could such an object be manipulated in 3D, scaled up and down and rotated using C#?

Answer (score 1):

Using the [Helix Toolkit](http://www.helix-toolkit.org/) I was able to get it one on-screen in a couple of minutes. One of their demo-apps renders a parametric surface on screen and allows you to change the equations. The 'magic' is in the math, which I copied from the [Mathematica StackExchange-site](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/94943/how-does-one-plot-a-m%C3%B6bius-strip):

```
u *= 2 * pi;
v = (v - 0.5) * 2 * pi;

x = ( 1 + (v/2) * cos(u/2)) * cos(u);
y = ( 1 + (v/2) * cos(u/2)) * sin(u);
z = (v/2) * sin(u/2);
```

On screen it looks like this:

[image: Screenshot of the Helix demo app showing a Möbius-band]